# Safely handle Hibernate "SET TRANSACTION must be first statement of transaction" error

Tags: hibernate, transactions, set, handler, rollback

I'm not sure if I'm asking the correct question to begin with, apologies in advanced.

#### Question

I am wondering if it is possible to have some type of handler to rollback an erroneous transaction in Hibernate.  I am having a problem which, whenever an error comes up during a batch update from Hibernate the "SET TRANSACTION must be first statement of transaction" error comes up and I would not be able to do any other query after that.

Thanks
:)

Comment: Was your issue resolved? I don't see any accepted answers or comments..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate don't have an automatic transaction management system, so you have to issue the begin, commit and roll back commands by yourself.

If you are using spring this can be a lot more easier with spring transaction management [API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

For example,

```
@Transactional
void updateFoo(Foo foo){
//do your stuff
}
```

In the above example a new transaction will be started at the beginning of the **updateFoo()** method commited at the last line. If there is any problem in between the transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, is there any other way besides using using annotations?

Comment: You can read it on the spring documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).