# Hibernate: saveOrUpdateAll and transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I am currently using version 3.3 of hibernate.

Currently the setting of hibernate is such that it will autocommit after each persistence of individual object.

I want to wrap a transaction around it, so it will only commit after end of a batch.

The code is in question:

```
  getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdateAll(collectionOfObject);
```

I have consulted the documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html), but want to see if there is alternative (other than rewriting it to use HSQL)

**EDIT**

My goal is to have a transaction around a bunch of insert. Currently it is auto-commit per insert

Comment: When you use `saveOrUpdateAll`, doesn't the ojects get saved to database? Why do you still need HSQL?

Comment: It is suggested by the documentation.

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you have a very large collection of object to be saved? If not, why don't you try the "naive example" in the document you linked there? That's exactly what you want, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use transaction management in **Spring** read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895803/safely-handle-hibernate-set-transaction-must-be-first-statement-of-transaction/7902444#7902444) on how to do it.

Also, Use should not be using `HibernateTemplate` use the `Session` object instead as below.

```
    sessionFactory = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    for (Bean bean : listBeans) {
        session.saveOrUpdate(bean );
    }
```

As there is no way to save the collection at one shot in session. This will commit the data after method exit.